# R fill several empty matrices with loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I would like to fill my created empty matrices with a loop:

First I have created my empty matrizes, which works fine:

```
for(q in (15:30)){
 assign(paste0("P",q), matrix(, nrow = q, ncol = q+1))}
```

But now when I want to fill these matrices with my formula, I get an dimension mistake:

```
   for(c in (1:q+1)){
    for(i in (1:q)){assign(paste0("P",q)[i,c],
((((((q-c) + 1 -(q-c+1- i))/q)^.69)/(((((q-c) + 1 - (q-c+1-i))/q)^.69+(((1 - ((q-c) + 1 -(q-c+1-i))/q))^.69))^(1/.69))) - (((((q-c)-(q-c+1-i))/q)^.69)/(((((q-c) - (q-c+1-i))/q)^.69+(((1 - ((q-c)-(q-c+1-i))/q))^.69))^(1/.69)))))}}}
```

Nevertheless when I use this loop for a single matrix it works e.g.:

```
 t <- 20
 c <- 1
 i <- 1
 for(c in (1:t+1)){
  for(i in (1:t)){P20[i,c]<-( (((((t-c) + 1 -(t-c+1-i))/t)^.69)/
                                      (((((t-c) + 1 - (t-c+1-i))/t)^.69+(((1 - ((t-c) + 1 -(t-c+1-i))/t))^.69))^(1/.69))) - 
                                     (((((t-c)-(t-c+1-i))/t)^.69)/(((((t-c) - (t-c+1-i))/t)^.69+(((1 - ((t-c)-(t-c+1-i))/t))^.69))^(1/.69))))}}
```

The formula is giving out probability weights according to Cummulative Prospect Theory, if anyone is interested.

Do you guys have an idea how I can make this more elegant? Should I better write a user-defined function?

Comment: Do you definitely want a `for` loop, it is possible to do this without

Comment: I am more than happy to do this without a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy with your resultant matrices being in a list with the same names you were assigning to you could do something like:

```
l = lapply(15:30, function(q){
  t = q
  matrix(apply(expand.grid(1:q,1:(q+1)),1,
        function(x){
          i = x[1]
          c = x[2]
          ( (((((t-c) + 1 -(t-c+1-i))/t)^.69)/
               (((((t-c) + 1 - (t-c+1-i))/t)^.69+(((1 - ((t-c) + 1 -(t-c+1-i))/t))^.69))^(1/.69))) - 
              (((((t-c)-(t-c+1-i))/t)^.69)/(((((t-c) - (t-c+1-i))/t)^.69+(((1 - ((t-c)-(t-c+1-i))/t))^.69))^(1/.69))))


        }),nrow = q, ncol = q+1, byrow = TRUE)
})
names(l) = paste0("P",15:30)
```

I have used bits like `t=q` and `i=x[1]; c=x[2]` such that I could just copy paste your formula for probability.

What we are doing here is using `lapply` to loop over the given row numbers in your question, we then use `expand.grid` to give the pairs of indicies for all cells in the resultant vector. To the indicies we apply a function which given row `i`, column `c` calculates the probability according to your formula. The values are then cast as a matrix such that the result has the appropriate structure.

You end up with a list `l` of matrices with components called "P15", "P16", ...

Comment: Thank you @jamieRowen for your help and especially for your detailed explanation.  But now I have to unlist the list "l", if I want to use the matrix further?

Comment: @Max, not at all. If you want to access an individual matrix you could do `l$P15`. You could also use `attach(l)` to bring all of the list values components into the global environment. I would suggest reading up on the dangers of attach before you decide whether this is a good idea for you. `unlist` will stack your matrices into one huge vector, which I suspect is not what you want.

Comment: Ok. So I need to modfiy my matrix further. Should I keep it in the list and then modify it?

Comment: You could keep it in the list if you want to. Whether or not the matrix is in the list will have little to no bearing on what you can do with it. In fact if you are going to modify each of the matrices in a similar fashion as here then it is likely beneficial to keep them all in a list as you can then use `lapply` again.